# Php / Perl : can't pass Html body of an email with "\n" to perl

Tags: php, perl, shell, system, newline

I have a Perl script that i's called by a Php function.

During the call i need to pass as arguments Header, Subject, Body.

But as we know Body can contain "new line" char for example:

```
Hello Mr x,

this is just a test
```

Normally we have two new line here.

So when i call the script using system() function :

```
system("perl /var/www/cgi-bin/daemon.pl $Header $Subject $body", $Res);
```

The body content will have just

```
Hello Mr x,
```

The result that i'am looking for is to have the possibility to pass the new line to perl and recieve the message exactly as is written.

Comment: Ya need to escape the command line arguments laddy. http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: You could use a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), but a much better solution (IMHO) would be to pipe to the perl script's STDIN.

Comment: Both of these comments are worth  of being answers and being selected. Although thatidiotguy's suggestion more directly answers your question, and DaveRandom's answer makes you modify your perl program.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help,

In my solution i used escapeshellarg() in my Php file and in the perl side i found [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/lib/HTML/Entities.pm)

with this i can encode and decode my agreement :

Here is my code :

Php file:

```
$Header = escapeshellarg($Header);
$Subject = escapeshellarg($Subject);
$Body = escapeshellarg($Body);

system("perl /var/www/cgi-bin/daemon.pl $Header $Subject $Body", $Res);
```

Perl Script :

```
#!/user/bin/suidperl -U
use HTML::Entities;

# The $Header , $Subject and $Body args are well received
# to pass this args to an other perl script i use encode_entities() function

encode_entities($Header);
encode_entities($Subject);
encode_entities($Body);
```

We can said that [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/lib/HTML/Entities.pm) is the same of [escapeshellarg.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) in PHP